# Ruby - Gem - mysql - Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby, debian, rubygems, redmine

since two days I'm facing a problem I can't solve. I'm trying to install redmine on a debian machine. When it comes to installation for the gem mysql it fails. I don't know what to do anymore. My last instance is your help.

## Error

```
root@host:~# gem1.8 install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.8
 --with-mysql-config
 --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

---

## What I've tried

- Installing packages by instruction: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/mysql#linux_ubuntu
- installing with mysql_config parameter
  root@host:~# find / -name mysql_config
  /usr/bin/mysql_config
  root@host:~# gem1.8 install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

---

## System

```
user@host:~# uname -a  
Linux www.example.org 2.6.18-028stab070.4 #1 SMP Tue Aug 17 18:32:47 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
root@s15428277:~# aptitude search '~i (mysql|ruby)|mysql.*dev'
i A libdbd-mysql-perl                                                     - A Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database                                
p   libghc6-hsql-mysql-dev                                                - Multi-Database Interface System for Haskell                                     
p   libgnademysql-dev                                                     - GNat Ada Database Environment - MySQL programming interface                     
p   liblua5.1-sql-mysql-dev                                               - luasql development files for the lua language version 5.1                       
i   libmysql++-dev                                                        - mysql C++ library bindings (development)                                        
i A libmysql++2c2a                                                        - mysql C++ library bindings (runtime)                                            
p   libmysql-ocaml-dev                                                    - OCaml bindings for MySql                                                        
v   libmysqlclient-dev                                                    -                                                                                 
i   libmysqlclient15-dev                                                  - MySQL database development files                                                
i A libmysqlclient15off                                                   - MySQL database client library                                                   
i   libopenssl-ruby1.8                                                    - OpenSSL interface for Ruby 1.8                                                  
i A libreadline-ruby1.8                                                   - Readline interface for Ruby 1.8                                                 
i A libruby1.8                                                            - Libraries necessary to run Ruby 1.8                                             
i   libsqlite3-ruby1.8                                                    - SQLite3 interface for Ruby 1.8                                                  
i A mysql-client-5.0                                                      - MySQL database client binaries                                                  
i A mysql-common                                                          - MySQL database common files                                                     
i   mysql-server                                                          - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)             
i A mysql-server-5.0                                                      - MySQL database server binaries                                                  
i   ruby1.8                                                               - Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby 1.8                      
i   ruby1.8-dev                                                           - Header files for compiling extension modules for the Ruby 1.8
```

```
root@host:~# gem1.8 --version
1.3.7
root@host:~# ruby1.8 --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

## Files

### mkmf.log

```
have_func: checking for mysql_ssl_set()... -------------------- no

"cc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lruby1.8-static -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))mysql_ssl_set; return 0; }
/* end */

"cc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lruby1.8-static -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { mysql_ssl_set(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_str_set_len()... -------------------- no

"cc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lruby1.8-static -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_str_set_len; return 0; }
/* end */

"cc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lruby1.8-static -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { rb_str_set_len(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... -------------------- no

"cc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lruby1.8-static -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_thread_start_timer; return 0; }
/* end */

"cc -o conftest -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC   conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lruby1.8-static -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient  -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: /*top*/
2: int main() { return 0; }
3: int t() { rb_thread_start_timer(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for mysql.h... -------------------- no

"cc -E -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC    conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include 
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for mysql/mysql.h... -------------------- no

"cc -E -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api    -I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC    conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include 
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: updated ruby  
    `ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: I had the same problem, for me the solution was to install gcc. Would have been nice if the error message said something about that. oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track. Even though you appear to have the mysql libraries installed, you need to ensure that the MySQL development header files and their dependencies are fully installed in order for the MySQL gem to be compiled.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-dev
```

And then:

> sudo gem install mysql --
>   --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Clearly, the exact command depends upon where the mysql-dev files are installed.

Comment: Hallo Scott. Thank you for the fast answer. But I've allready installed the dev for the mysql. (libmysqlclient15-dev)

Comment: Okay. Sorry Johannes. Well it was worth a try.

Comment: Of course, and I'm very thankful for every comment and hint.
And `gem install mysql` with the mysql config didn't work either.

Comment: I have another thought: Perhaps your Ruby install is too old or incomplete. 2008-08-11 is two years old, and things move fast in the Ruby/Gems world. You could try installing the latest ruby via RVM to bring everything fully up to date.

Comment: The requirements of redmine are ruby1.8 (http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineInstall#Ruby-xx-Ruby-on-Rails-xx-Rack)
So I've to stay at ruby1.8

Comment: Yep, that's true, and I hear you... but the latest Ruby 1.8 was released in August 2010: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/16/ruby-1-8-7-p302-is-released/ Very often the default versions of Ruby found in Linux distributions are outdated and slightly broken! You can update and still have Ruby 1.8 compatibility!

Comment: Ahh, okay. I give it a try. Thank you

Comment: okay, I've added the backports of lenny and upgraded ruby  
`ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]`
it still doesn't work.

Comment: Damn! Sorry to hear that it didn't work. I've run out of ideas for now; however, I still believe that you are now in a better position to get it working with the upgrade. I hope someone else will be able to add to this discussion.

Comment: after a few tries I found the error. I'm hosted at 1und1 v-server and there are special debian repos in their source.list. But the mirror servers of 1und1 aren't up to date, so i've downloaded always wrong or damaged packages. I've reinstalled the server with the offical debian repos and everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: I had to use `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` rather than `mysql-dev`, but this was really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
The solution for me was to install ruby-dev.
Maybe it helps somebody else, I see you've already solved your porblem.